# Is constructor generated default constructor?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to find out by reflection whether a constructor is a compiler generated default constructor or not? Or is there some other way?

Surprisingly the `isSynthetic` method does not give this information so it can't be used. And there is no `Generated` annotation present.

```
public class JavaTest {
    public void run() throws Exception {
        out.println(JavaTest.class.getConstructors()[0].isSynthetic()); // Prints false
        out.println(Arrays.asList(JavaTest.class.getConstructors()[0].getAnnotations())); // Prints []
    }
}
```

This question asks the same thing but for C#: [Detect compiler generated default constructor using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190575/detect-compiler-generated-default-constructor-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I guess the answer'd be same as C#'s answer :)

Comment: Automatic default constructor is definitely a language design mistake. In an ideal world, it doesn't exist, so why do you even care:) What feature depends on the detection of default constructor?

Comment: Automatic default constructor are great! It's for doing static analysis. If I know that a constructor is default than I know, by only looking of the declaration on the class, that it is empty and doesn't, for example, leak the `this` pointer anyplace.

Comment: @Lii, I believe you are mistaken about the lack of a constructor implying no leak of `this` during construction. I can easily write a class that has no explicit constructor, but has an (instance) initializer block that uses `this`. Have a look at http://ideone.com/5uPJJU

Comment: @DilumRanatunga: Ah, you are right of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the compiler generates them:

I created the file `A.java`:

```
public class A{
public String t(){return "";}
}
```

then:

```
javac A.java
```

and running `javap -c A` to see the content:

```
Compiled from "A.java"
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public java.lang.String t();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 
       2: areturn       
}
```

if I add the constructor:

```
public A(){}
```

the result is:

```
Compiled from "A.java"
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public java.lang.String t();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 
       2: areturn       
}
```

it's identical. I'm using Java 7 with 64 bit OpenJDK, but I'd bet that it's the same with all the versions.

*EDIT*: in fact, the same bytecode alone doesn't guarantee that the information is not present as metadata. Using an hex editor and [this program](http://classfileanalyzer.javaseiten.de/) was possible to see that there are two bytes differing, and correspond to the line numbers (used for printing stack traces), so the information is absent in this case.

Comment: It seams reasonable that a generated default constructor and an empty constructor produce the same bytecode. But there could still be some meta data with information about this.

Comment: Ah, examining the class file in a raw data editor should settle it! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no metadata in the bytecode that would allow you to distinguish a compiler generated default constructor from a non-generated one.

In most cases, compiler generated constructors and methods are marked with the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag or the `Synthetic` attribute in the generated bytecode. However, there are a few notable exceptions as per 13.1 item 7 from the [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) and 4.7.8 from the [jvm-spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.8)

Here is the relevant bit from the JLS:

> Any constructs introduced by a Java compiler that do not have a corresponding construct in the source code must be marked as synthetic, **except for default constructors**, the class initialization method, and the values and valueOf methods of the Enum class

As far as I know, `javap` does not show the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag but you would be able to read it through `isSynthetic` if it was set.

Comment: `javap -verbose` does show flags, including `ACC_SYNTHETIC`.