# How to check if a java class contain a default constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I want to check if a Java class contains a default constructor.

Case 1 :

```
public class ClassWithConstructor {

    //attributes...

    //default constructor
    public ClassWithConstructor(){}

}
```

Case 2 :

```
public class ClassWithoutConstructor {

    //attributes...

    // no default constructor

}
```

In case 1 , I want to print `"ClassWithConstructor contains a default constructor."`

In case 2, I want to print `"ClassWithoutConstructor doesn't contain any default constructor"`.

Comment: but in case 2 there is a default constructor

Comment: Both have the default constructor of Object

Comment: keep in mind if `ClassWithoutConstructor` has no constructor then you will actually have a default constructor.

Comment: Actually, it's vice versa - case 1 does not have a default constructor, since you've overriden it. default constructor is the one generated by java when you don't provide it

Comment: i dont want to consider the default constructor added by the compiler , what i want, is checking if my class contains this part of code : public classname( ){ }

Comment: How and when do you want to check this? At runtime? From a binary? By parsing source code?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619041/is-constructor-generated-default-constructor

Comment: hey reto ,i want to check this, in a separate class, for example in the main method of an other  java class.

Comment: hey Paul Boddington, thanks for the link, but i want just to check if my java class contains this snippet code :  public classname() {}

Comment: That's called a **no-argument constructor**.

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect your class via the Java Reflection API, there is a class called `Constructor` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-frame.html). Not sure, though, whether you can actually distinguish the Java default constructor and a parameterless one you defined on your own.

Comment: hey FleshWound , thank you for the link, i check this solution using Reflection API , but it doesn't gave me  what i want. we can say i want to search a word in java class, so my word is "public classname() {}" , i want to check if my java class contains this word.

Comment: That would involve looking at the source code. You don't have the source code available at run time.

Comment: ... unless you manually parse the source files at file level, of course.

Comment: One might be temped to use `Constructor.isSynthetic()` (or inspecting the symbol modifiers) but (generated) default constructors are not considered synthetic. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46699

Comment: Though on a second thought, the generated default constructor has a package private visibility so any public no-arg constructor detected has a good chance to be explicitly declared as OP requested.

Comment: The implicit default constructor has package private visibility for top-level classes, but can have different visibility for nested classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check this case. The class without constructors creates a default constructor with the same attributes that a `public ClassName(){}`, nevertheless you can check if the modifier or attributes change.

If you debug this code, you will see that both Constructors[] have the same attributes except the clazz, they have the distinct name.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ScriptBuilderTest {

@Test
public void test()  {

    Class<ObjectWithDeclaredConstructor> ObjectWithDC = ObjectWithDeclaredConstructor.class;
    Class<ObjectWithoutDeclaredConstructor> ObjectWithoutDC = ObjectWithoutDeclaredConstructor.class;

    Constructor<?>[] ctorsWithDC = ObjectWithDC.getDeclaredConstructors();
    Constructor<?>[] ctorsWithoutDC = ObjectWithoutDC.getDeclaredConstructors();

    System.out.println("end");
}

public class ObjectWithDeclaredConstructor{
    public ObjectWithDeclaredConstructor(){}
}

public class ObjectWithoutDeclaredConstructor{  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much guys , i didn't find what i want, so i will check manually my package that contains 456 entities if any one of them doesn't contains a default constructor.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are on a Unix System, try with a bash script to find the declared constructors in files, or with a powershell script in MS Systems.

Comment: hey viticlick, im using mac , can i do it with script, can you give me more explanations please?.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** In case 1, you don't have a default constructor. But in case 2, you have a default constructor. In case 1 the constructor is created by you, not by your compiler. In Java, the compiler is always responsible for creating a default constructor. In case 1 the compiler code looks like below.

```
public class ClassWithConstructor {


    public ClassWithConstructor(){
         super();//This code is generated by compiler
     }

}
```

S0 `super()` is generated by the compiler since the first line of the constructor should be `this()` or `super()`. Since it does not have anything I created `super()`.